# What to do on android HttpURlConnection

Tags: java, android, string, encoding, authentication

As you can see from my code, I'm trying to programmatically log into a website using post/get...

I'm using the following code in Java, and it's working awesome.
But when I run this same code on android, the app doesn't work.
If I'm doing some encode its run but with wrong parameters!
So what do I have to do ?

```
final String httpParams=String.format("__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2FEoMVGnzRVw%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDQKVkZe1BALj4YiXBgLltMbPAwKI0bD9DwKQxtj8BgL5%2B6qZBALP14C2DAL6qc7jBwLN49KjCQLo0YK0CQLS%2BavhCwKh5%2FXjDQLizN68CiDA9ZDgCfU8Py%2Bfp0mFjtZo08Sp&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24UserName=%s&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Password=%s&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24LoginButton=Login&ctl00%24hdnCurClientTimeZone=%2B02%3A00",userId,password);

try {
    wr = new DataOutputStream($.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(httpParams);
    wr.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: try this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: You should first format() the string and afterwards url encode it.

Comment: I understand that but if I do it the string will no be the string that I want and the website will not accept the parameters as right prams